# ¿Cómo comprobar la presencia de un atributo con Selenium y obtener su valor si es aqui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

itero en [un google forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform) y trato de poner algo de contenido (que trato de hacer que parezca una cita por si acaso). Sin embargo algunos campos son edades y no permiten tener más de 99 años como este:

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Age" aria-describedby="i.desc.504994172 i.err.504994172" name="entry.128750970" value="" min="18" max="99" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="10102015" badinput="false" aria-invalid="true">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que añadí una condición en mi código para tratar de ver si hay un atributo `max` en los elementos en los que tengo que escribir:

```
        content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
        )
        for content_area in content_areas:
            if content_area.get_attribute("max") exists:
                max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
                content_area.send_keys(max)
            else:
                content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

Pero no funciona:

```
max:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "questions_scraper_michael.py", line 151, in <module>
    result = extract(driver, df, column)
  File "questions_scraper_michael.py", line 70, in extract
    "freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer"
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 580, in find_elements_
by_class_name
    return self.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements

    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_respo
nse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text :
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Comment: lo que no entiendo es bien qué precisas? Para qué quieres obtener el maximo si estás enviando por parámetro hardcodeado un número que supera ese max? Lo que no te funciona es obtener el 99? Podrías esclarecer tu pregunta así podemos ayudarte? gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que apuntas a la clase equivocada, ese elemento en concreto tiene como atributo `class`:

> class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput"

así que debes buscar por una de estas tres formas:

- `"quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput"`
- `"quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput.exportInput"`
- `"exportInput"` (todos los cuadros de texto de la página la comparten)

Un ejemplo simplificado (solo considera la primera página del formulario) mostrándolo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


form_link = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe-ebOztdB6T4ZgtsOYuvbUR5qwSTfI5CnJB1mNLeNflCVX8Q/viewform"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(form_link)

containers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
    "freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer"
    )
for container in containers:
    try:
        question = container.find_element_by_class_name(
            "freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle"
            )
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue

    inputs = container.find_elements_by_class_name("exportInput")
    for input in inputs:
        print(f"• Text input encontrado en '{question.text}'")
        max = input.get_attribute("max")
        min = input.get_attribute("min")
        if min:
            print(f"  - Mínimo encontrado: {min}")
        if max:
            print(f"  - Máximo encontrado: {max}")
        else:
            print("  - Input sin valores mínimos ni máximos establecidos")

driver.quit()
```

> ```
> • Text input encontrado en 'Age *'
>   - Mínimo encontrado: 18
>   - Máximo encontrado: 99
> • Text input encontrado en 'Gender *'
>   - Input sin valores mínimos ni máximos establecidos
> • Text input encontrado en 'State (Two letter Abbreviation) *'
>   - Input sin valores mínimos ni máximos establecidos
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema en tu código está en que en el if te falta el sendkeys, ya que lo único que le estás diciendo es que si existe, tome el dato y lo guarde en Max pero no haces nada con ese dato.

No debería ser:

```
content_areas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "quantumWizTextinputSimpleinputInput.exportInput"
        )
        for content_area in content_areas:
            if content_area.get_attribute("max") exists:
                max = content_area.get_attribute("max")
                content_area.send_keys(max)
            else:
                content_area.send_keys("10102015")
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Desafortunadamente, Max permanece vacío